# How can compile a simple windows application using cmake and Visual Studio 2019?

Tags: c++, windows, visual-studio, cmake, no-response

I opened a new windows desktop-application project in Visual Studio 2019 and it brought a C++ starting code. I compiled it and it ran well. It is a simple window with two menus as "File" and "Help" only.

What I want to do is to copy this starting code to a cmake project and make it work. Actually I did it and compiled without any error.

*My problem is that when I clicked the compiled exe (CMakeProject7.exe) nothing happens. If I use the console to run the exe same thing happens. I can't even see it in the task manager. It runs and closes instantly.*

With CMake I tried X64-Debug and X64-Clang-Debug. There is only one warning if I use X64-Clang-Debug which is : *"warning : unused variable 'hdc' [-Wunused-variable]
                  HDC hdc = BeginPaint(hWnd, &ps);"*  In case of X64-Debug, there is no warning.

I collected all of the code in **CMakeProject7.cpp** for better follow. It is below:

```
// CMakeProject7.cpp : Defines the entry point for the application.
//

//#pragma once
#include <SDKDDKVer.h>
//#define WIN32_LEAN_AND_MEAN             // Exclude rarely-used stuff from Windows headers
// Windows Header Files
#include <windows.h>
// C RunTime Header Files
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <malloc.h>
#include <memory.h>
#include <tchar.h>
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

#define IDS_APP_TITLE           103

#define IDR_MAINFRAME           128
#define IDD_CMakeProject7_DIALOG    102
#define IDD_ABOUTBOX            103
#define IDM_ABOUT               104
#define IDM_EXIT                105
#define IDI_CMakeProject7           107
#define IDI_SMALL               108
#define IDC_CMakeProject7           109
#define IDC_MYICON              2
#ifndef IDC_STATIC
#define IDC_STATIC              -1
#endif
// Next default values for new objects
//
#ifdef APSTUDIO_INVOKED
#ifndef APSTUDIO_READONLY_SYMBOLS

#define _APS_NO_MFC                 130
#define _APS_NEXT_RESOURCE_VALUE    129
#define _APS_NEXT_COMMAND_VALUE     32771
#define _APS_NEXT_CONTROL_VALUE     1000
#define _APS_NEXT_SYMED_VALUE       110
#endif
#endif


#define MAX_LOADSTRING 100

// Global Variables:
HINSTANCE hInst;                                // current instance
WCHAR szTitle[MAX_LOADSTRING];                  // The title bar text
WCHAR szWindowClass[MAX_LOADSTRING];            // the main window class name

// Forward declarations of functions included in this code module:
ATOM                MyRegisterClass(HINSTANCE hInstance);
BOOL                InitInstance(HINSTANCE, int);
LRESULT CALLBACK    WndProc(HWND, UINT, WPARAM, LPARAM);
INT_PTR CALLBACK    About(HWND, UINT, WPARAM, LPARAM);

int APIENTRY wWinMain(_In_ HINSTANCE hInstance,
    _In_opt_ HINSTANCE hPrevInstance,
    _In_ LPWSTR    lpCmdLine,
    _In_ int       nCmdShow)
{
    UNREFERENCED_PARAMETER(hPrevInstance);
    UNREFERENCED_PARAMETER(lpCmdLine);

    // TODO: Place code here.

    // Initialize global strings
    LoadStringW(hInstance, IDS_APP_TITLE, szTitle, MAX_LOADSTRING);
    LoadStringW(hInstance, IDC_CMakeProject7, szWindowClass, MAX_LOADSTRING);
    MyRegisterClass(hInstance);

    // Perform application initialization:
    if (!InitInstance(hInstance, nCmdShow))
    {
        return FALSE;
    }

    HACCEL hAccelTable = LoadAccelerators(hInstance, MAKEINTRESOURCE(IDC_CMakeProject7));

    MSG msg;

    // Main message loop:
    while (GetMessage(&msg, nullptr, 0, 0))
    {
        if (!TranslateAccelerator(msg.hwnd, hAccelTable, &msg))
        {
            TranslateMessage(&msg);
            DispatchMessage(&msg);
        }
    }

    return (int)msg.wParam;
}



//
//  FUNCTION: MyRegisterClass()
//
//  PURPOSE: Registers the window class.
//
ATOM MyRegisterClass(HINSTANCE hInstance)
{
    WNDCLASSEXW wcex;

    wcex.cbSize = sizeof(WNDCLASSEX);

    wcex.style = CS_HREDRAW | CS_VREDRAW;
    wcex.lpfnWndProc = WndProc;
    wcex.cbClsExtra = 0;
    wcex.cbWndExtra = 0;
    wcex.hInstance = hInstance;
    wcex.hIcon = LoadIcon(hInstance, MAKEINTRESOURCE(IDI_CMakeProject7));
    wcex.hCursor = LoadCursor(nullptr, IDC_ARROW);
    wcex.hbrBackground = (HBRUSH)(COLOR_WINDOW + 1);
    wcex.lpszMenuName = MAKEINTRESOURCEW(IDC_CMakeProject7);
    wcex.lpszClassName = szWindowClass;
    wcex.hIconSm = LoadIcon(wcex.hInstance, MAKEINTRESOURCE(IDI_SMALL));

    return RegisterClassExW(&wcex);
}

//
//   FUNCTION: InitInstance(HINSTANCE, int)
//
//   PURPOSE: Saves instance handle and creates main window
//
//   COMMENTS:
//
//        In this function, we save the instance handle in a global variable and
//        create and display the main program window.
//
BOOL InitInstance(HINSTANCE hInstance, int nCmdShow)
{
    hInst = hInstance; // Store instance handle in our global variable

    HWND hWnd = CreateWindowW(szWindowClass, szTitle, WS_OVERLAPPEDWINDOW,
        CW_USEDEFAULT, 0, CW_USEDEFAULT, 0, nullptr, nullptr, hInstance, nullptr);

    if (!hWnd)
    {
        return FALSE;
    }

    ShowWindow(hWnd, nCmdShow);
    UpdateWindow(hWnd);

    return TRUE;
}

//
//  FUNCTION: WndProc(HWND, UINT, WPARAM, LPARAM)
//
//  PURPOSE: Processes messages for the main window.
//
//  WM_COMMAND  - process the application menu
//  WM_PAINT    - Paint the main window
//  WM_DESTROY  - post a quit message and return
//
//
LRESULT CALLBACK WndProc(HWND hWnd, UINT message, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam)
{
    switch (message)
    {
    case WM_COMMAND:
    {
        int wmId = LOWORD(wParam);
        // Parse the menu selections:
        switch (wmId)
        {
        case IDM_ABOUT:
            DialogBox(hInst, MAKEINTRESOURCE(IDD_ABOUTBOX), hWnd, About);
            break;
        case IDM_EXIT:
            DestroyWindow(hWnd);
            break;
        default:
            return DefWindowProc(hWnd, message, wParam, lParam);
        }
    }
    break;
    case WM_PAINT:
    {
        PAINTSTRUCT ps;
        HDC hdc = BeginPaint(hWnd, &ps);
        // TODO: Add any drawing code that uses hdc here...
        EndPaint(hWnd, &ps);
    }
    break;
    case WM_DESTROY:
        PostQuitMessage(0);
        break;
    default:
        return DefWindowProc(hWnd, message, wParam, lParam);
    }
    return 0;
}

// Message handler for about box.
INT_PTR CALLBACK About(HWND hDlg, UINT message, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam)
{
    UNREFERENCED_PARAMETER(lParam);
    switch (message)
    {
    case WM_INITDIALOG:
        return (INT_PTR)TRUE;

    case WM_COMMAND:
        if (LOWORD(wParam) == IDOK || LOWORD(wParam) == IDCANCEL)
        {
            EndDialog(hDlg, LOWORD(wParam));
            return (INT_PTR)TRUE;
        }
        break;
    }
    return (INT_PTR)FALSE;
}
```

**CMakeLists.txt** is the following:

```
cmake_minimum_required (VERSION 3.8)

project(CMakeProject7)

# Add source to this project's executable.
add_executable (CMakeProject7 WIN32 "CMakeProject7.cpp")
```

Comment: Tried debugging?

Comment: @arrowd Yes. It executes the code `if (!InitInstance(hInstance, nCmdShow)) { return FALSE;}` and this one in the exe : `if (!__scrt_is_managed_app()) exit(main_result);` and hence exits. I think it is an initialization problem but I don't understand why.

Answer (score 3):

The global variables `szTitle` and `szWindowClass` are empty since we need to have a ressources file to fill it:

```c
LoadStringW(hInstance, IDS_APP_TITLE, szTitle, MAX_LOADSTRING);
LoadStringW(hInstance, IDC_CMakeProject7, szWindowClass, MAX_LOADSTRING);
```

To fix it, we have two ways:

1. Copy the orginal ressources file `CMakeProject7.rc` and add it to the executable:

```
cmake_minimum_required (VERSION 3.8)

project(CMakeProject7)

# Add source to this project's executable.
add_executable (CMakeProject7 WIN32 "CMakeProject7.cpp" "CMakeProject7.rc")
```

*NOTE:* We need also to copy ico files

2. Do not use a rc file but we need to change a little the program:

- Comment/Remove this lines:

```c
LoadStringW(hInstance, IDS_APP_TITLE, szTitle, MAX_LOADSTRING);
LoadStringW(hInstance, IDC_CMakeProject7, szWindowClass, MAX_LOADSTRING);
```

- Change the `szTitle` and `szWindowClass` declarations:

```cpp
LPCWSTR szTitle = L"CMakeProject7";
LPCWSTR szWindowClass = L"CMAKEPROJECT7";
```

- Change the function `MyRegisterClass()` to remove references to icon files or menu toolbar:

```cpp
ATOM MyRegisterClass(HINSTANCE hInstance)
{
    WNDCLASSEXW wcex;

    wcex.cbSize = sizeof(WNDCLASSEX);

    wcex.style = CS_HREDRAW | CS_VREDRAW;
    wcex.lpfnWndProc = WndProc;
    wcex.cbClsExtra = 0;
    wcex.cbWndExtra = 0;
    wcex.hInstance = hInstance;
    wcex.hIcon = NULL;
    wcex.hCursor = LoadCursor(nullptr, IDC_ARROW);
    wcex.hbrBackground = (HBRUSH)(COLOR_WINDOW + 1);
    wcex.lpszMenuName = NULL;
    wcex.lpszClassName = szWindowClass;
    wcex.hIconSm = NULL;

    return RegisterClassExW(&wcex);
}
```

In both cases, we need configure the project to use Unicode instead of ANSI. Just add this lines at the end of `CMakeLists.txt`:

```
target_compile_definitions(CMakeProject7
  PRIVATE "UNICODE;_UNICODE"
)
```